# WebStorm TypeScript code style spaces inside if\else

Tags: typescript, webstorm

How to change settings of code style to get this spaces like on the screen ?
I mean for autoformatting.

[image]

Comment: Editor -> Code Style -> Typescript -> Tabs and Indents.

Comment: but i need Indents only inside if\slse

Comment: I'd say that's really uncommon requirement to have different indent for specific keywords (if/else)

Comment: There are no rules for line indents inside specific contructs